# Обращения к примитивам string как к обьектам получается засоряют память создавая множество обьектов-оберток String?

Tags: javascript, производительность, сборщик-мусора

Вот такой вот вопрос возник ‍♂️

```js
var s = "test"
for (let i = 0; i < s.length; i++) {
    s.coronovirus = true // обращаемся как к обьекту -> создается обертка
    console.log(s.charAt(i) + " " + s.coronovirus) // s.coronovirus будет false, т.е. обертка создается для каждого обращения и сразу уничтожается
}
```

Не проблема ли это? Сильно влияет на производительность создание кучи одноразовых обьектов? Только начал изучать JavaScript, впечатлило это

Comment: Современные JS движки практически никогда не создают объекты-обёртки для примитивов. Ну и GC не дремлет и такие короткоживущие объекты вычищаются быстро и эффективно.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Да, примитивы работают быстрее, объекты - медленее, но не намного. Смотрите подробнее [здесь](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/12/performance-with-javascript-string-objects/). Статья, конечно, устарела, но она наглядно показывает, что производительность падает. На момент написания статьи разница была высокой, но в современных браузерах разница уже очень маленькая. Запустите тесты из статьи и посмотрите сами. Критично ли это - зависит от ситуации. Вообще как часто вы пользуетесь огромными массивами текстовых данных в JavaScript? Почти никогда. В JavaScript есть вещи гораздо более критичные по отношению к производительности (например работа с DOM). Так что работа со строками почти всегда не самое узкое место в обычном web-приложении.

Comment: интересная статья. Жаль в книжке (javascript-подробное руководство)  не написано что интерпретатор не создает обертки при обращении к дефолтным свойствам